# Pandas will not treat "Null" as a regular word -- converting to Nan

Tags: pandas, null

I want to leave Null as a normal word and not have it be blanked out or treated as NaN. I've tried keep_default_na=False.

I've tried converters={'string':str)}.  These cause the Null to be replaced with just a blank.  If I do nothing, it gets changed to NaN, which I don't want.  I hope you'll have ideas. Thanks.